# Getting exception while executing build of same jobs in parallel

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, dsl

I'm getting exceptions while running builds of the same job in parallel. I'm passing arguments like `CHROME_DRIVER`, `GECO_DRIVER`, and on the basis of number of arguments the build must be created and executes in parallel. My child job name is sample.

This is my code to execute job builds in parallel:

```
    def driver=params.DRIVER.split(',')
    paramBValue = params.MODULE_IID
    def testJobs=[]
    for (int i=0;i<driver.size();i++) { 
    paramAValue=driver[i]
    println paramAValue
    def testJob = { 
    build job: 'sample', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 
   'DRIVER', value: paramAValue], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 
   'MODULE_IID', value: paramBValue]] 
    } 
    println testJob
    testJobs.add(testJob) 
    } 

    parallel(testJobs)
```

I am passing arguments and on the basis of number of arguments I want to build jobs in parallel, but I am getting the following exception:

```
    Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
    [Pipeline] echo
    CHROME_DRIVER
    [Pipeline] echo
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@b139f6
    [Pipeline] echo
    GECO_DRIVER
    [Pipeline] echo
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@1d5fc61
    [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got 
    [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@b139f6, 
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@1d5fc61]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.singleParam(DSL.java:537)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:525)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:465)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:183)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:15)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1249.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock$LocalVariable.get(LocalVariableBlock.java:39)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock.evalLValue(LocalVariableBlock.java:28)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$BlockImpl.eval(LValueBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock.eval(LValueBlock.java:16)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:19)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:35)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:331)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:243)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:231)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to fix the args to `parallel`.  Following the example at [Pipeline Examples](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#parallel-from-list) maybe something like:

`testJobs.add([ "some name": testJob ])`

(...or whatever the proper Groovy syntax would be.)

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot.